# redirecting name cheap to firebase hosting and masking URL

Tags: firebase, dns, redirect, firebase-hosting, namecheap

Lets say I have my firebase hosting at my 
app.firebaseapp.com

Now I use namecheap and want to redirect 
redirect.mydomain.com ---->  https://app.firebaseapp.com

I have this setup and it works. But after the redirect works, the browser bar shows " https:// app.firebaseapp.com)

How do I mask this such that no one ever see's  https://app.firebaseapp.com and all that is visible is redirect.mydomain.com ?

Comment: I am totally confused now. Do I also need to setup subdomain redirects on name cheap along with connecting the domain on Firebase to get this to work ?

OR
Do I just need to connect the domain to firebase and not bother about subdomain redirecting to work ?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Create a subdomain on Namecheap. Connet the subdomain to Firebase. Add the A entries provided by Firebase. DO NOT add any redirection on Namecheap. Just create the subdomain and follow Firebase instructions. Give it an hour.